# Error while linking 16-bit asm code

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, masm32

This is the program I am trying to assemble & link. But I get a linker error:

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 5.12.8078
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.

LINK : error : Segment reference in fixup record
A05ASM1.obj : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
```

I am using the following commands to assemble and link:

- command for assemble: `ml /c a04asm1.asm`
- command for linking:  `link a04asm1.obj`

```
page 60, 132  

TITLE         A04ASM1 (EXE) Move and add operations    
;-------------------------------------------------------------  
STACK             SEGMENT PARA STACK 'Stack'  
          DW      32 DUP(0)  
STACK         ENDS  
;-------------------------------------------------------------   
DATASEG       SEGMENT PARA 'Data'               
FLDD          DW      215  
FLDE          DW      125  
FLDF          DW      ?  
DATASEG       ENDS  
;-------------------------------------------------------------  
CODESEG       SEGMENT PARA 'Code'       
MAIN          PROC    FAR  
ASSUME  SS:STACK,DS:DATASEG,CS:CODESEG  

  MOV     AX,DATASEG  
  MOV     DS,AX  
  MOV     AX,FLDD  
  ADD     AX,FLDE  
  MOV     FLDF,AX  
  MOV     AX,4C00H  
  INT     21H  

MAIN              ENDP  
CODESEG           ENDS  
END     MAIN
```

Comment: You need the 16-bit "segmented" linker for this: ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/Softlib/MSLFILES/LNK563.EXE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the 16-bit linker for this to work, try:

```
assemble: ml /c a04asm1.asm
link16 a04asm1.obj
```

Comment: thnx this worked for me. could you tell me how do I know when to use link16 and when to use only link command? Is there any way to find out the way to check whether the code is for 16 bit or some other ?

Comment: the explanation given in the link is good. but I am still confused. I just want to understand how someone can figure out the code snippet asked in the question is using 16 bit notations and should be linked by 16 bit linker ? Is it because of the segments used or some other stuffs(keywords that are meant for only 16 bit) used there ?

Comment: @dev - One thing is that you're using a 16bit DOS interrupt (int 21h), read more: http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html

Comment: Now I understood. Its because of the 16 bit keywords and instructions being used in the code. and that code can't be linked using 32 bit linker.